# Cassandra : query to retrieve all matched data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to make query to Cassandra table to get all the matched request with specific data_id and date_period. But am getting only single matched data

Here is my query-

```
   @Query("select * from customer_data where data_id = ?0 and date_period = ?1")
```

What I am doing wrong?
DO i need to add any field in this table? like count or something??

```
     {
  "groupingTime": 107,
  "id": "7b24970e40d244b96",
  "tnoid": "f3-2f2b086d9b19",
  "productId": "FIDCWBADVR",
  "groupReq": false,
  "ReceiptDate": "06/13/2015,05:55:22",
  "tnoDate": "06/13/2015,05:55:25",
  "tnoFile": ""
   }
```

Comment: Give more information, such as your table structure and some sample data, otherwise with the information provided it is difficult to answer.

Comment: when i am making this query, i am getting this table data

Comment: What is the schema ?